# Slack dialog accessory static select not wokring

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, slack, slack-api, slack-dialog

I'm trying to open a slack modal.
The following is my JSON. The value is not passed when the field is put under accessory. I'm getting an error next to the field. Am I doing anything wrong? The same thing works when I put it inside input type blocks. Below is JSON code I built using Slack Block Kit Builder. I have added action_id also

```
{
    "type": "modal",
    "title": {
        "type": "plain_text",
        "text": "My App",
        "emoji": true
    },
    "submit": {
        "type": "plain_text",
        "text": "Submit",
        "emoji": true
    },
    "close": {
        "type": "plain_text",
        "text": "Cancel",
        "emoji": true
    },
"blocks": [
            {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "mrkdwn",
                "text": "To"
            },
            "accessory": {
                "type": "static_select",
                "action_id": "to_time",
                "placeholder": {
                    "type": "plain_text",
                    "text": "Select an item",
                    "emoji": true
                },
                "options": [
                    {
                        "text": {
                            "type": "plain_text",
                            "text": "8 AM",
                            "emoji": true
                        },
                        "value": "8"
                    },
                    {
                        "text": {
                            "type": "plain_text",
                            "text": "9 AM",
                            "emoji": true
                        },
                        "value": "9"
                    },
                    {
                        "text": {
                            "type": "plain_text",
                            "text": "10 AM",
                            "emoji": true
                        },
                        "value": "10"
                    },
                    {
                        "text": {
                            "type": "plain_text",
                            "text": "11 AM",
                            "emoji": true
                        },
                        "value": "11"
                    },
                    {
                        "text": {
                            "type": "plain_text",
                            "text": "12 PM",
                            "emoji": true
                        },
                        "value": "12"
                    },
                    {
                        "text": {
                            "type": "plain_text",
                            "text": "1 PM",
                            "emoji": true
                        },
                        "value": "1"
                    },
                    {
                        "text": {
                            "type": "plain_text",
                            "text": "2 PM",
                            "emoji": true
                        },
                        "value": "2"
                    },
                    {
                        "text": {
                            "type": "plain_text",
                            "text": "3 PM",
                            "emoji": true
                        },
                        "value": "3"
                    },
                    {
                        "text": {
                            "type": "plain_text",
                            "text": "4 PM",
                            "emoji": true
                        },
                        "value": "4"
                    },
                    {
                        "text": {
                            "type": "plain_text",
                            "text": "5 PM",
                            "emoji": true
                        },
                        "value": "5"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The value is not passed

[image: This is the block]

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`views.open`](https://api.slack.com/methods/views.open) instead of `dialog.open`. Since you are using block elements inside modal and hence it's suggested to use [`view.open`](https://api.slack.com/methods/views.open) I hope this works for you.

Then check whether you have added a webhook for the interactive component.
[image]

Look's like the issue with your webhook URL can you please check once again? I tried with your JSON and it work's like a charm!

**Code:**

```js
    const data = {
        token: authToken,
        trigger_id: trigger_id,
        view: {
            // Json goes here
        }
    };
    const headers = {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${authToken}`
    }
    const response = await axios.post(`${apiUrl}/views.open`, data, { headers });
    console.log(response.data);
    return response;
```

**Dialog:**

[image]

**Success Response:**

[image]

Comment: I have used views.open only

Comment: Then, have you added interactive webhook in your slack app?

Comment: Yea I have added. When I use input block. It works. But accessory doesn't return values

Comment: in view_submission, it is something like this  ....type: 'modal',
    blocks: [ [Object] ],
    private_metadata: '',
    callback_id: '',
    state: { values: {} },